# jOOQ with java 15: both interface org.jooq.Record in org.jooq and class java.lang.Record in java.lang match

Tags: java, jooq, java-record, java-15

I've just tried upgrading my project to Java 15, and now I get the following error:

```
  both interface org.jooq.Record in org.jooq and class java.lang.Record in java.lang match
```

Does anybody have some experience resolving this issue?

Comment: Use `import org.jooq.Record;` instead of just `import org.jooq.*;`

Comment: You can track this issue here https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9988

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to what [Aniket already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63939555/521799):

#### Import-on-demand no longer works for `Record`

The recommendation is to add an explicit import to your import-on-demand statement:

```java
import org.jooq.*;
import org.jooq.Record;
```

Or to stop using import-on-demand entirely. E.g. in Eclipse, you can use the "Organize Imports" feature to expand all your import-on-demand statements to explicit imports, depending on the types you're actually using.

#### Using type inference

Another way to prevent this problem if it happens with local variables is to use `var`:

```java
var record = ctx.fetchOne(TABLE, TABLE.ID.eq(1));
```

Now you don't have to import the type. This doesn't work with member types, method parameter and return types, of course.

We'll try to better document this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10646

Answer (score 5):

Java 14 introduced [records](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/datum.html). `java.lang.Record` is a superclass of `record` which is conflicting with `org.jooq.Record` since every type in `java.lang` is auto imported. There are two solutions:

1. Use a fully qualified name instead of `Record` and remove the import. Eg: `org.jooq.Record` instead of `Record`. (Don't forget to remove the `import` statement).
2. Redeclare the `org.jooq.Record` to something specific. (Which I believe is not possible in your case as it's a third-party library.)